# What is the difference between scatter and scatter3D in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter3d

As long as projection is set to 3d in the call to add_subplot or axes, such as `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')`, both scatter and scatter3D plot a 3D plot. So what is the point of using scatter3D?

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like `scatter3D` is just an alias for scatter in the source code ~L2190: `scatter3D = scatter`. Would explain the same results https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.6.2/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L2116-L2188